# Severe lock contention from LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitForSignal

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a `dotnet` 6 app that suffers from severe lock contention, 60% of the CPU time.
Most of the contention originates from a stack that I have no control of (see below picture):

```
879,559 ms in System.Threading.LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitForSignal(int)

Stack trace

System.Threading.LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitForSignal(int)
System.Threading.LowLevelLifoSemaphore.Wait(int, bool)
System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
```

My app:

- Processes events from `Azure Eventhubs`
- Uses dotnet's [TPL (Task Processing Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) extensively

I'm trying to better understand what this stack suggests.
My suspicion is that:

- Dotnet creates more *ThreadPool* threads
- Thread creation uses locks extensively (for some reason?)
- This is a side-effect of a different issue relating to my app's logic

**Is there anything I can do to mitigate this side-effect directly?**, thinking about the throughput-loss because of these 60% contention blows my mind.

[image: lock contention]

Comment: I think this is a complete red herring. The thread pool threads wait for stuff to do, they are contending on a queue, and therefore doing nothing as they are supposed to. Possibly you have more threadpool threads than normal due to poor use of `Task.Run` or similar, but without seeing actual code it's hard to say.